# Insert data from a form into a specific table based on the id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a set of data in the database name subjects with 4 columns ['id','sub_name','sub_code','sub_group'. The initial data for the database are as follows

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+
| id | sub_name | sub_code |sub_group|
+----+----------+----------+---------+
|  1 |     A    |   S01    |  0      |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
|  2 |     B    |   S02    |  0      |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
|  3 |     C    |   S03    |  0      |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
```

The things that I try to do is to update the 'sub_group' value to "group 1/group 2/group 3" through a form,
I have try to follow some of the tutorial but its fail. Below are the code that I have tried. Hopefully, someone can help me..

This is my code in HomeController

```
public function updateGroup(Request $request)
   {
       $group = Subject::find($request->subject_id);
       $group->sub_group = $request->sub_group;
       $group->save();

       return redirect('/dashboard');
   }
```

This is my code in Subject.php model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'sub_group'
    ];
```

This is my code in view

```
 <form method="post" action="/dashboard">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
  <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead class="text-warning" align="center">
     <th>No.</th>
     <th>Subject Name</th>
     <th>Subject Code</th>
     <th>Subject Group</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     @foreach ($subject as $index => $sub)
      <tr align="center">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{$sub->sub_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$sub->sub_code}}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="col">
              <select class="form-control" name="sub_group">
              <option disabled selected>Assign Group...</option>
              <option value="group1">Group 1</option>
              <option value="group2">Group 2</option>
              <option value="group3">Group 3</option>
              </select>
              <input type="hidden" name="subject_id" value="{{$sub->id}}">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>   
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
   </form>
```

based on my form, user can only fill up the option for 'sub_group' only and I try to replace the existing value in database for 'sub_group' with the latest value that user choose ('group1/2/3')

This is my code in web.php

```
Route::post('/dashboard', 'HomeController@updateGroup');
```

I expect the current 'sub_group' data will be updated with the value that the user chooses from the form. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't have a `name` attribute on your select input.

Comment: @aynber thank you, I have updated the code..

Comment: Can you post the route definition for the endpoint you are posting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating multiple records with one POST. This means that, rather than posting a single ID, you need to post an associative array to the server that maps IDs to values.

You also, presumably, want this `<select>` to display the current value in the `sub_group` column. To do this, I would update your markup as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sub_group_{{ $sub->id }}">
  <option disabled{{ !($sub->sub_group) ? ' selected' : ''}}>Assign Group...</option>
  <option value="group1"{{ ($sub->sub_group == 'group1' ? ' selected' : '' }}>
    Group 1
  </option>
  <option value="group2"{{ ($sub->sub_group == 'group2' ? ' selected' : '' }}>
    Group 2
  </option>
  <option value="group3"{{ ($sub->sub_group == 'group3' ? ' selected' : '' }}>
    Group 3
  </option>
</select>
```

Your server will receive data that looks something like this:

```
[
  'sub_group_1' => 'group1',
  'sub_group_2' => 'group2',
  'sub_group_3' => 'group3'
]
```

Now, in your controller, you need to parse the ID from the key, lookup the database record, and save the new value:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

...


public function updateGroup(Request $request)
{
  foreach($request->all() as $key => $value) {
    if (Str::startsWith($key, 'sub_group_')) {
      $id = explode('_', $key)[2];
      $group = Subject::find($id);
      $group->sub_group = $value;
      $group->save();
    }
  }

  return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/Lhvu26rn/15/) you can use to see what your form will submit to the server.

Comment: Error : Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Str' not found but I already declare use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Str and run composer require illuminate/support. Do u know how can i solve this?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` I'll update the answer.

Comment: error: Undefined offset: 2 and it highlight this  $id = explode($key, '_')[2]; I'm not sure what does it mean this is my first time see this coding technique.

Comment: Sorry, another mistake... it should be `explode('_', $key)[2]`

Comment: the php `explode` function splits a string into an array based on the passed delimiter – in this case, the delimiter is the `_` character. So the result is the array `['sub', 'group', '1']`, so index 2 is the ID.

Comment: sry for the late reply, I've fall asleep yesterday.. I will try your solution after I finish my class today..

Answer (score 0):

First give name to select

```
<select class="form-control" name="sub_group">
              <option disabled selected>Assign Group...</option>
              <option value="group1">Group 1</option>
              <option value="group2">Group 2</option>
              <option value="group3">Group 3</option>
              </select>
<input type="hidden" name="subject_id" value="{{$subject_id}}">
```

**Update**

Actually you need to pass the `$id` in the form as a hidden input field because of post request. Then in the controller function you will get `subject_id` from the request object

```
public function updateGroup(Request $request)
   {
       $group = Subject::find($request->subject_id);
       $group->sub_group = $request->sub_group;
       $group->save();

       return redirect('/dashboard');
   }
```

Comment: I got this error "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::updateGroup(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Comment: The second part of this answer is unnecessary, and would require an update to your route definition as well. Leave your controller code alone.

Comment: Ok.. @MohdAsyraf kindly try with your own controller function

Comment: @ZainFarooq your code update the 'sub_group' but the problem now  it update only the last id which is C, for A and B still remain as '0' even I choose 'group1' for both of it.

Comment: It will update the row of id which you are passing in the input hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="subject_id" value="{{$subject_id}}">`

Comment: It all depends on the `$subject_id`

Comment: You can change the `$subject_id` to 1 or 2 manually to check the results

Comment: when I press submit it should submit the 'sub_group' for $subject_id 1,$subject_id 2, and $subject_id 3 right ? but it seems like the 'sub_group' for last subject_id only changed.. I have updated my code with your suggestion but it only works for last subject_id. @ZainFarooq

Comment: So, are you passing multiple input fields for subject_id?

Comment: @MohdAsyraf see my updated answer. I think I understand your problem now.

Comment: ya I send subject_id for '1,2 and 3' at the same time

Comment: No, You should send only one at a time. For sending multiple ids you need to use multi-select input field

Comment: @MohdAsyraf Kindly go through [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-multiselect-dropdown). You will need to use multiselect input field to send multiple subject_id's

Comment: @Vince I will have a look at your suggestion

Comment: No, multiselect is not the right solution here. That would be useful if the OP wanted to save **multiple** groups to **one** subject. That is not the case.

Comment: @ZainFarooq I try for Vince suggestion

Comment: @Vince It is useful because the OP needs to change the multiple `sub_group`'s

Comment: @ZainFarooq, read the question again. Look at the markup. It is clear that the OP is not trying to select multiple groups.

Comment: @Vince. Read the comment section of my answer. The OP is trying to update the multiple groups

Comment: You've misunderstood what OP wants. Read my answer.